# Service Container is not updating with environment variables

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to update environment variables in an existing container through image definition file.

image definition.json

```
{
 "taskDefinition": {
"family": "testrepository",
"containerDefinitions": [
  {
    "name": "testrepository",
    "image": "046940809212.dkr.ecr.us-east2.amazonaws.com/testrepository",
 "environment":[
  {"name":"AW_API_KEY","value":"7265376200510qo25cgkv0pfa086fvc158of76no8m74. apps.googleusercontent.com"},
  {"name":"AW_API_SECRET" ,"value":"n0mw1g7Yri70-oMrJ4zd9T3h"}
      ],

    "portMappings": [
      {
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ]
  }
],
    "cpu": 100,
    "memory": 128,
    "essential": false
  }
}
```

I am trying to update it through buildspec.yml file.

my buildspec.yml

`post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on`date
      `- echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - printf '[{"name":"testrepository","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
    files: imagedefinitions.json`

Note: I am not getting any error it was successful with default blank values while running the task.